# question about group by

Tags: mysql

in mysql how to write a sql like this, to get the amount of X > 20 and <20

> select date, numberOfXMoreThan20,numberOfXLessThan20, otherValues
>
> from table
>
> group by (date, X>20 and X<20)

my way, but i think it's not good

> select less20.id_date, a,b
>   from 
>       (select id_date,count(Duree_Attente_Avant_Abandon) as a from cnav_reporting.contact_global where Duree_Attente_Avant_Abandon>20 group by id_date) as less20,
>       (select
>   id_date,count(Duree_Attente_Avant_Abandon)
>   as b from
>   cnav_reporting.contact_global where
>   Duree_Attente_Avant_Abandon<20 group
>   by id_date) as more20
>
> where
>
> less20.id_date=more20.id_date

thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
  date,
  SUM( IF(X > 20), 1, 0 ) AS overTwenty,
  SUM( IF(X < 20), 1, 0 ) AS belowTwenty,
  otherValue
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `date`, `otherValue`
```

Comment: Because you're using a dot instead of a comma :) Replace '),1.0)' by '),1,0)'

Comment: @chun my answer always had commas, not dots :)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the `COUNT` aggregate:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table Where X > 20
```

Comment: I would agree to just use two queries. You could get both counts in one query but that would get needlessly complicated.

Comment: sorry, i mean to get the count about X>20 and aslo <20, i knwo that with 2 select i can do this ,but is it possible to use just one select with group by to get this done